# Firefox is caching ajax form values from previous submit after if I press the browser back button

Tags: 8, forms, ajax

I've implemented a custom multistep AJAX form like:

STEP #1
Question 1: A or B (radiobutton Ajaxified) -> AjaxCallback: step + 1

STEP #2
Question 2: C or D (radiobutton Ajaxified) -> AjaxCallback: step + 1;

STEP #3
Question 2: E or F (radiobutton Ajaxified) -> redirect to other page (ajax command)

Everything works as expected but after being redirected to the new page if I click the browser back button in firefox the form shows the first step with the option [A] selected of the first step. This does not happen in Chrome.

I'm running Firefox 54.0.1

Does it make sense to anyone? How could I fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

It seems chrome makes a refresh of the page and firefox a cache. Seeing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31837195/chrome-vs-firefox-back-caching) the reasons are answered [here](https://madhatted.com/2013/6/16/you-do-not-understand-browser-history)

You can try disabling caches using http headers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13640109/how-to-prevent-browser-cache-for-php-site

Answer (score 2):

On Drupal 8, I was having an issue with Firefox that was caching the value of a  field, selected by the user before refreshing the page.

It was basically overriding the #default_value of the field.

My solution was to Turn Off Form Autocompletion (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion).

You can do it at the level on the input if that's an , but since it was a  in my case I had to do it at the form level :

```
$form['#attributes']['autocomplete'] = 'off';
```

Comment: This also works in Drupal 7 and on individual form elements.